# mongoengine referencefield not updated

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have 3 `Document` classes:

```
class Policy(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)

class Group(Documet):
    # ...
    policy = ReferenceField('Policy', db_field='policy_id')

class Item(Document):
    foo = StringField()
    group = ReferenceField(Group, db_field='group_id')
```

Now - when I set Item -> Group -> Policy relationship, all is fine until I update the policy.

I'm doing it in a code that eventually changes .name in a `Policy` type object (will call it x) and run `x.save()`

The DB in the correct policy gets updated perfectly, none of the `ObjectId`s change (nor the `ReferenceField` object)

But still:

```
item = Item.objects.get(foo='needed_item')
policy = item.group.policy
```

`policy.name` contains the old value (as if it was not updated at all)

Do `ReferenceField` has a manual "refresh" I need to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the instance stored in memory then you need to call the [`reload`](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/apireference.html?highlight=reload#mongoengine.Document.reload) method on the document.

Comment: Thanks. It seems kind of lame that every time I access a ReferenceField I need to call reload afterwards. I would have expected that calling .save will figure it out and make it dirty...